# SQL: Select IDs which are not mapped to values in another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with two columns like this:

```
ROLE_ID      RESTRICTION_ID
---------    ---------------
2            null
2            15
2            null
13           12
13           null
13           13
555          null
555          null
555          null
91           10
91           12
91           null
```

I need to get:

```
    ROLE_ID      RESTRICTION_ID
    ---------    ---------------
    555          null
    555          null
    555          null
```

Meaning , that i need all ROLE_ID's which are not connected to any RESTRICTION_ID.

If there is some number in the RESTRICTION_ID column for some ROLE_ID is want the ROLE_ID excluded from the select statement results.

Comment: select * from A where RESTRICTION_ID is null and
    ROLE_ID not in (select ROLE_ID from A where RESTRICTION_ID is not null); ... it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
    table t1
    LEFT JOIN table t2
    ON t1.ROLE_ID = t2.ROLE_ID
    AND t2.RESTRICTION_ID IS NOT NULL
WHERE
    t2.ROLE_ID IS NULL
```

Just because everyone else is showing the WHERE IN (SELECT ... answer here is a way to do it via a self join....

And just to show one way it can be done using EXISTS...

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
    table t1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
             FROM
                table t2
             WHERE
                t1.ROLE_ID = t2.ROLE_ID 
                AND t2.RESTRICTION_ID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks. The first query did the job.

Answer (score 2):

Select the rows where resctriction_id is null

```
select * from my_table 
where resctiction_id is null
and role_id not in (select role_id from  my_table  where resctiction_id is not null) ;
```

Comment: I see you answer IN (SELECT id.. a lot I would recommend looking at using EXISTS because if someone happens to get a null in the select statement they will not get the results they want and Exists is generally touted as faster. with that said still good up vote one of the better answers paying attention to all requirements that I read in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROLE_ID, RESTRICTION_ID
FROM Table
WHERE
ROLE_ID NOT IN (SELECT ROLE_ID FROM Table WHERE RESTRICTION_ID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: @RoberColumn  .. I'sorry i have edit you post .. ..wrongly ..please post you orginal answer ..

Comment: Why the embedded SELECT statement? The data set does not appear to have NULL in the role ID column

Comment: @kbball  i have update the wrong answer so i done a mess ..i'm sorry

Comment: @showdev   how  i   can rollback .. ? please explain me

Comment: @showdev   thank you very much  .. I have done  .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROLE_ID, RESTRICTION_ID
FROM <Your Table>
WHERE RESTRICTION_ID IS NULL
AND ROLE_ID NOT IN 
(SELECT ROLE_ID FROM <Your Table> WHERE RESTRICTION_ID IS NOT NULL) sub
```

Comment: @Dave That's what he said he needs right? Am I misreading the question?

Comment: He wants the role_id where all of the associated restrictions are null. You'll get 2,2,13... :) You were right with the correction to mine though.

Comment: Gotcha ok now I get it

Answer (score 0):

```
Select role_id, restriction_id
From Table 
Where role_id in (Select ROLE_ID

From Table
Group by ROLE_ID
Having COUNT(RESTRICTION_ID)=0)
```

Better maybe...

Comment: he doesn't want the IDs grouped. His desired answer shows the IDs repeated

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you started:

```
SELECT
  role_id
  , restriction_id
FROM Data
WHERE role_id NOT IN
 (SELECT
    role_id
  FROM Data
  GROUP BY role_id
  HAVING COUNT(restriction_id) > 0
 );
```

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: The query doesn't return any results for me.

Comment: @PhilipSt: Re-tested: `WITH Data (role_ID, restriction_ID) AS (
  SELECT 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 555, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 555, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 555, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 91, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 91, 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 91, NULL FROM DUAL
)`

Comment: `SELECT
  role_id
  , restriction_id
FROM Data
WHERE role_id NOT IN
 (SELECT
    role_id
  FROM Data
  GROUP BY role_id
  HAVING COUNT(restriction_id) > 0
 );` - and got your expected result. Did you modify the query?

Answer (score 0):

and becuase you have tagged SQL here is a Window function with common table expression that does the job nicely as well.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,COUNT(RESTRICTION_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ROLE_ID) as CountOfRestrictionsIds
    FROM
       TableName
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    CountOfRestrictionsIds = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Count them all

```
with t as (
    -- sample data
    select 2 as ROLE_ID  ,null as RESTRICTION_ID from dual union all
    select 2    ,15   from dual union all
    select 2    ,null from dual union all
    select 13   ,12   from dual union all
    select 13   ,null from dual union all
    select 13   ,13   from dual union all
    select 555  ,null from dual union all
    select 555  ,null from dual union all
    select 555  ,null from dual union all
    select 91   ,10   from dual union all
    select 91   ,12   from dual union all
    select 91   ,null from dual 
)
select ROLE_ID,RESTRICTION_ID
from (
    select t.* 
        ,count(RESTRICTION_ID) over(partition by ROLE_ID)  as cnt
    from t
    ) x
where cnt=0;
```

Comment: isn't this the same as one my answer only 2 hours after I posted mine?

Comment: Apparently it is. I've just overlooked your answer, sorry.